# C# - Using Razor Components In A Razor Page - @onclick event don't work

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, blazor

I've an existing "Razor Page Web Project", and I've added my component as explain here:
https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/338/using-razor-components-in-a-razor-page

After this, I've build and used my personal component. This as rendered correctly, but after added an @onclick event in a tag, this seem not work correctly (event not triggered)

**Theoretically** I've done all correct steps, and I've already check for a solution, but without success:

1. in my startup.cs:

> in ConfigureServices:  services.AddServerSideBlazor();
>
> in Configure:
>
> ```
> app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
>             {
>                 endpoints.MapRazorPages();
>                 endpoints.MapBlazorHub();   
>                 endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host"); 
>             });
> ```

2. [+]: Components folder
3. [+]: _Imports.razor inside my Components folder

> ```
> @using System.Net.Http
> @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
> @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
> @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
> @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
> @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
> @using Microsoft.JSInterop
> ```

4. [+]: in my _Layout.cshtml (at the end of the Body TAG, after others script):

> ```
> <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
> ```

5. [+]: App.razor in the root of the project:

> ```
> @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
>
> <Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
>     <Found Context="routeData">
>         <RouteView RouteData="routeData" />
>     </Found>
>     <NotFound>
>         <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">         
>             <h1>Page Not Found</h1>
>             <p>Sorry, but there's nothing here!</p>            
>         </div>
>     </NotFound>
> </Router>
> ```

Now, my razor component (inside the Components folder):

> ```
> @inherits LateralMenuComponent
>
> @if (IsAuthenticate)
> {
>     <div class="mt-3"> 
>         <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-toggle" role="toolbar" aria-label="Common Toolbar">
>             <a type="button" class="btn btn-warning text-left" href=".\">
>                 <img src="src/dash.png" class="float-left pr-3" />
>                 Dashboard
>                 <span class="badge badge-light">@BadgeAlert</span>
>             </a>
>             @if (MenuItems != null)
>             {
>                 foreach (var vitem in MenuItems)
>                 {
>                     <a type="button" class="btn btn-secondary text-left" href="@vitem.Function.PagePath"
>                        @onclick="UpdateHeading">  @* <--- [/!\] event trigger, pls note this! *@
>                         <img src="src/@vitem.Function.ImageShort" 
>                              class="float-left pr-3" />@vitem.Function.Label
>                     </a>
>                 }                
>             }
>         </div>
>     </div>
> }
> ```

whit relative componentBase:

> ```
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic; 
>
> namespace myAppWeb.Components
> {
>     public class LateralMenuComponent : ComponentBase
>     {        
>       [Parameter] public bool IsAuthenticate { get; set; }>           
>       [Parameter] public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }>     
>       [Parameter] public short BadgeAlert { get; set; } = 3; // 3 => Draft, TO_DO!
>
>
>       // [/!\] - This don't work!
>         public void UpdateHeading(MouseEventArgs e)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine(e);        
>         }
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Are you able to help me understand what I'm doing wrong in my environment?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

As Vencovsky correctly suggested in a comment below, the problem was that I was using **static** rendering, so no clicks could be triggered in this case - a trivial problem, I know ...

Comment: Have you tried `@onclick:preventDefault` in the `a` tag?

Comment: If I try with **@onclick:preventDefault="UpdateHeading()"**, this is triggered, but in rendering only (like as a "onLoad") and not on the click event (and without args...)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `@onclick:preventDefault`

```
<a href="" @onclick="@SomeAction" @onclick:preventDefault />
```

Working example on [blazorfiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/aoa87v05).

Comment: it doesn't work for me .... same behavior. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @mymark please check [this owrking example](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/aoa87v05). Are you doing it like this? What exactly isn't working? Maybe the function is being called but you just don't see the console?

Comment: I think it's banal, but it's about the way I make the render. It was **RenderMode.Static**, so it didn't allow triggering. Maybe **RenderMode.Server** is better ...

Comment: @mymark if you user `Static`, no click will be trigger